# ActiveRecord custom validators not executing when calling form.yiiActiveForm("validate")

Tags: javascript, php, yii2, active-form

I wanted to verify the contents of an ActiveForm without submiting the form.
I'm currently doing this in javascript with following code

```
var form = $(this).closest('tr').find('form');
var data = form.serialize();

d = form.data("yiiActiveForm");
$.each(d.attributes, function() {
  this.status = 3;
});

form.yiiActiveForm("validate");
if (form.find(".has-error").length) {
    return false;
}
```

This works fine and the errors are shown in the screen 
when validating on predefined active form validators defined in rules() function of ActiveRecord.

```
array_push($r, ['tel_no', 'required', 'message' => 'input telephone no.']);
array_push($r, ['mail_address', 'email', 'message' => 'input correct email']);
```

but not on custom validator like the following

```
array_push($r, ['card_no', 'validateCardNo']);


public function validateCardNo($attribute, $params) {
    if (!preg_match('/^[A-Za-z0-9-\/]+$/D', $this->$attribute)) {
        $this->addError('card_no', 'input correct card no');
    }
}
```

Do I need something on my javascript in order to also trigger the custom validators? Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks in advance

Comment: You need to use [enableAjaxValidation property](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-input-validation.html#ajax-validation). No need to use js.

Answer (score 1):

To create a validator that supports client-side validation, you should implement the yii\validators\Validator::clientValidateAttribute() method which returns a piece of JavaScript code that performs the validation on the client-side.

See the documentation: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-input-validation.html#implementing-client-side-validation

Answer (score 0):

For reference, I was able to call the custom validator by calling validateAttribute.

```
form.yiiActiveForm("validate");
form.yiiActiveForm("validateAttribute", "user-card_no");
if (form.find(".has-error").length) {
    return false;
}
```

and also setting the enableAjaxValidation to true in view side.

```
<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(['id' => 'owner_form', 'enableAjaxValidation' => true]); ?>
```